# vinyl plotting via cups and inkcut

Tags: printing

with Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 it was easy to send hpgl data to my Roland vinyl cutter. I connected the plotter via usb, let cups install the plotter automatically, chose "raw queue" and sent the data from the inkscape extension "inkcut 1.0".

With Ubuntu 17.10 and CUPS 2.2.4 there is now "raw queue" printing option any more. I've tried several others like text only, pcl and what not, but with no success. The communication with the plotter works, but with "text only" it cuts the vinyl to random slices - that's what it looks like to me. Other than that I get various errors on the plotter.

I know that Inkcut 1.0 is really old, but I don't know of any alternatives. Does anybody have an idea how to send hpgl paths with a recent cups, ideally from a gui like inkcut?

Many thanks, especially because the vinyl-cutting-on-linux-community seems not to be that big.

Comment: Tuxplot http://securetech-ns.ca/tuxplot.html has been mentioned in various forums: the guy who manages it seems to be very active and available for advice;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to stackoverflow, I found it! If the plotter is installed via the webinterface at localhost:631` it shows usb://Roland/GX-300?serial=0001. Under "make" it lists "Raw". Inkcut is great!